# "Was/were" and "would be/would have been"

Tags: grammar, american-english, subjunctives

If this ... (was/were) the case, the movie ... (would be/would have been) much better.

The context is that I am sending my friend a video of a movie trailer (not released yet), and it has some funny things added to it, but it will never be in the movie itself. What would be the correct way to write the sentence I mentioned based on the context?

Comment: If you are talking about a forthcoming or newly released movie, you would probably use _would be_. For an older film, "It _would have been_ much better".